# How to filter objects according to the selected month in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a `Customer` model. This model has a `created_date` field.

I want to list all customers created in the selected month. I think I can use `timedelta` for that but I cannot figure out how can I applied that.

How can I filtering the customers according to the selected month?

**views.py**

```
def log_records(request):
 ....
form = MyForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            months = cd.get('months')

 selected_month = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=...somethin...)
 selected_month_customers = Customer.objects.filter(company=userP[0].company, created_date__gte=last_month.count()
 ...
 context = {'selected_month_customers': selected_month_customers,...}
 return render(request, 'logs.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
...
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
...
```

**forms.py**

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    MONTH_CHOICES = [
        ('January', 'January'),
        ('February', 'February'),
        ('March', 'March'),
        ('April', 'April'),
        ('May', 'May'),
        ('June', 'June'),
        ('July', 'July'),
        ('August', 'August'),
        ('September', 'September'),
        ('October', 'October'),
        ('November', 'November'),
        ('December', 'December'),

    ]
    months = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=MONTH_CHOICES), label="Select a month ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do like that - `Customer.objects.filter(created_date__month=<month_number>)`